# Ajax is not working on wamp

Tags: ajax, wampserver

this is my client side code.The server side php code is simply to echo statement.

```
function load(){if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari     
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlhttp");}
    if(xmlhttp==null)
    { alert ("Your browser does not support XMLHttpRequest!");
        return; }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.write("Received");
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/tphp.php?", true);/*this works separately*/
    xmlhttp.send();document.write("Sent")}
```

**My html code contains**

```
<h4 id="txtHint">to be replaced</h4>
<input type="button" onclick="load()" value="click" />
```

**My PHP code it contains echo statement.i just want to test it**

```
<?php
echo "It's working";
?>
```

Comment: If i use the URL in a new tab then it works.so no error on server side code..plz help me

Comment: Is your client-side code being served from the same server? AJAX by default can't cross domains, this includes when the client-side script is called from the file system (`file:///...`).

Comment: Also don't include the domain in the URL. Just use `"/tphp.php?"`.

Comment: BTW, your code looks very chaotic. At least make sure the indentation is correct, and avoid `document.write` even/especially for test code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can use jQuery, if so please make these things simple:

```
$("body").append("Sent<br/>");
$.get("/tphp.php", function (data) {
  $("body").append("Received: " + data + "<br/>");
});
```

Advantages of using jQuery:

1. Code is simple.
2. Excellent cross browser support.

Comment: I am just checking ajax with javascript in WAMP.My code is correct but server is not responding.But the same server works with normal client server with refreshing .it fails incase of AJAX

Comment: @Venkat Could be there... Can you post the full code of the PHP file also by editing the question?

Comment: but page loads forever when i click

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you called load() function correctly. Check your console.

```
function load() {

   console.log("Called");
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
     }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/tphp.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
   }
```

Comment: Yes.load() funtion is executed.but onreadyreadystatechange is not executed.